# Importing a postgis1.5 based dump into a postgis2.0 database

Tags: postgresql, postgis, heroku-postgres

I have a self hosted database using postgis1.5 / postgres9.1. I would like to import that data into a heroku postgres db with postgis2.0 installed.

How can I convert the db? or otherwise do this? Without upgrading my existing postgres/postgis setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Heroku, so I'm just suggesting a procedure. You will need to temporarily self-host an installation of PostgreSQL 9.1/PostGIS 2.0 to properly convert the database and PostGIS data. Follow the steps [in the manual for a Hard upgrade](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade). I would do this on a virtual machine that is similar to the OS used by Heroku. After it has been converted, then try to bring it into Heroku.